# Sections based on hourly/minute wise data using fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a 3 days data stored in CoreData. The timestamp is stored as TimeInterval(Double) format. Can I use the NSFetchedResultsController to get sections based on half hourly or hourly or every 5 minutes ?  My intention is to plot the data on a graph every half hourly/hourly/5 minutes wise.

Comment: No.  `NSFetchedResultsController` requires a distinct value in a particular key to group objects into sections.  You will need to load all of the data into an array and crunch the data yourself.

Comment: I used a transient attribute to get sections based on hour. For that, a date formatter, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HHZ" was used for the grouping. But I am not able to do the grouping for half hourly. So, no compound section key path possible right?